# Swift - constrain UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uilabel, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` and I would like to constrain it the same way as I would a `UILabel`. But if I use the same `constrains` as I would with a `UILabel` I am getting a different result. I also do not really quite understand how `UITextView.frame` works because it doesn't really matter what I set `height/width`, the result stays the same.

In the picture below "LinkTest" is my `UITextView`. As you can see it is not lined up with the `UILabels` below even though I `constrain` it the same way.

[image]

**UITextView:**

```
    let linkLabel: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        v.text = "Link"
        v.textColor = .lightGray
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18)
        v.textAlignment = .right
        v.isSelectable = false
        v.isScrollEnabled = false
        v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
//        v.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
```

**Constrains:**

```
// constrain linkLabel
    linkLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkImage.topAnchor).isActive = true
    linkLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    linkLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

    // constrain priceLabel
    priceLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkLabel.topAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
    priceLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    priceLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

    // constrain noteLabel
    noteLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceLabel.topAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
    noteLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    noteLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

I appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

The problem was the `UITextViews` `padding`. Removing all padding solved the problem:

```
let padding = v.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding
 v.textContainerInset =  UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -padding, bottom: 0, right: -padding)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set

```
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

then frame setting is ignored , btw you need a height

```
linkLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

Comment: I added changed that but it still looks the same. I also added the same `height.constraint` to `priceLabel` and `noteLabel`

Comment: I don't get why `linkLabel` is not right-aligned like `priceLabel/noteLabel` ..

Answer (score 0):

You can set constraints using frame or using autolayout both can not work at same time. when you set `v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` then frame setting doesn't affect and also you have to add height constraint

```
// constrain linkLabel
    linkLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkImage.topAnchor).isActive = true
    linkLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    linkLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    linkLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
```

Comment: I added changed that but it still looks the same. I also added the same height.constraint to priceLabel and `noteLabel`

Comment: You added trailing  and leading constraint for all three label with same distance but link label has long text which is not fit as per your defined constraints. So you can try to remove trailing constraint and add width constraint for your link label and check.

Comment: the user can type in any text he wants. Removing trailing constrain just moves the textView to the left